# Is it possible to unlock new guns without using Multiplayer?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront

From my experience, the only way to unlock new guns in Star Wars Battlefront is to get them in Multiplayer. Is there a way to get new guns in Solo mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you don't *need* to unlock guns in Singleplayer. It already has all the guns available in the game. You're probably thinking of Star Cards. These are only available as pre-made hands. However, if you complete any mission on Hard difficulty, you unlock your Multiplayer hand.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately nope. Contracts are only tracked in online mode.